# Как создать библиотеку импорта для существующей DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

Есть несколько DLL, требуется использовать функции из них в проекте на Си++. Доступа ни к исходникам ни к разработчикам у меня нет. То есть в наличии просто набор DLL как вешь в себе и документ с описанием интерфейса к ним.

Сейчас я получаю адреса функций вручную c помощью `LoadLibrary` и `GetProcAdrress`, но под мою задачу было бы удобнее иметь библиотеки импорта для них. Чтобы никаких телодвижений по инициализации не делать, не следить за ними и так далее. Так вот, как библиотеки импорта создать и вообще как они работают?

Comment: Эээ, а разработчики этих библиотек предоставляют вам эти библиотеки в пользование? Если да, то с ними должны идти `lib`-файлы или header'ы. Если нет, то вы делаете что-то не то.

Comment: То есть вы в принципе можете создать руками файл library.h с кодом наподобие `extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall function(int, char*);` (или какая там calling convention), но если такого файла у вас нет, вы делаете что-то неправильно. И вам всё равно нужно слинковаться с `lib`.

Comment: Вот тут описан хак: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131313

Comment: @VladD А если они на Delphi написаны, с ними тоже lib должны идти?

Comment: @VladD Ваш последний коментарий это именно тот ответ который я искал. Пожалуйста, запостите его как собственно ответ, а я вам за это галочку поставлю :)

Comment: Неее, ответы-ссылки — зло. Написал нормальный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе, это неподдерживаемый сценарий: например, функции могут быть декорированы нестандартным образом, или иметь нетрадиционное соглашение о вызове.

Но тем не менее, если вы знаете точную сигнатуру функций, то можно попытаться сделать, как описано [здесь](http://web.archive.org/web/20150510233939/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131313).

Идея №1: создать DEF-файл вручную. Это подойдёт, если функции, которые вы импортируете, есть C-функции, и вы знаете их calling convention (например, `__cdecl` или `PASCAL` (`__stdcall`)).

Для начала, установим, что это за функции. Для этого можно воспользоваться стандартной [утилитой dumpbin с ключом /exports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0.aspx) (не забывайте, что её нужно запускать из-под Visual Studio command prompt) или очень полезной при нативной разработке под Windows-платформу [утилитой depends.exe](http://dependencywalker.com/).

Для dumpbin вы получите примерно такой вывод:

```
...> dumpbin /exports "C:\Program Files\Far\Plugins\arclite\arclite.dll"
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Program Files\Far3\Plugins\arclite\arclite.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for arclite.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    54BA6E68 time date stamp Sat Jan 17 15:15:04 2015
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
          19 number of functions
          19 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          2    0 00016170 AnalyseW
          3    1 00016920 CloseAnalyseW
          4    2 000175F0 ClosePanelW
          5    3 000182A0 ConfigureW
          6    4 00017DA0 DeleteFilesW
          1    5 000185E0 ExitFARW
          7    6 00017B00 FreeFindDataW
          8    7 00017B60 GetFilesW
          9    8 000179F0 GetFindDataW
         10    9 00015F20 GetGlobalInfoW
         11    A 000177C0 GetOpenPanelInfoW
         12    B 00016030 GetPluginInfoW
         13    C 00017EC0 MakeDirectoryW
         14    D 00016970 OpenW
         15    E 00017FD0 ProcessHostFileW
         16    F 00018180 ProcessPanelInputW
         17   10 00017C80 PutFilesW
         18   11 000178A0 SetDirectoryW
         19   12 00015FB0 SetStartupInfoW

  Summary

        5000 .data
       16000 .rdata
        9000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       87000 .text
```

Отсюда вы берёте имена функций: `AnalyseW`, `CloseAnalyseW` и т. д., и превращаете их в .def-файл:

```
EXPORTS
; EntryName [=InternalName] [@Ordinal] [NONAME] [CONSTANT]
AnalyseW
CloseAnalyseW
```

Так работает для функций с calling convention `__cdecl` (она обычно принята по умолчанию). Для других вы должны задекорировать имя функции самостоятельно, согласно [таблице](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx):

```
| Calling convention                    | extern "C" or .c file | .cpp, .cxx or /TP |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| C convention (__cdecl)                | _test                 | ?test@@ZAXXZ      |
| Fastcall convention (__fastcall)      | @test@0               | ?test@@YIXXZ      |
| Standard call convention (__stdcall)  | _test@0               | ?test@@YGXXZ      |
| Vector call convention (__vectorcall) | test@@0               | ?test@@YQXXZ      |
```

— и [прописать их как алиасы](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140485):

```
EXPORTS
; EntryName [=InternalName] [@Ordinal] [NONAME] [CONSTANT]
CdeclFunction
PascalFunction=_PascalFunction@8
```

(число после `@` означает количество байт в стеке, отводимое под параметры).

Теперь можно использовать команду `lib /def:yourfile.def` из командной строки Visual Studio, чтобы построить .exp и .lib для линковки.

---

Идея №2 — это создать фейк-библиотеку с такими же сигнатурами функций, построить её, и использовать её .exp и .lib вместо отсутствующих. Для этого вам придётся построить С- (или хуже того, C++-) сигнатуры нужных функций. Для сишных функций (ну или тех, которые были определены как `extern "C"` в исходнике) это просто: вы смотрите на декорированное имя (например, в том же depends.exe или dumpbin), определяете по таблице сверху их calling convention, и кладёте такую функцию в исходник. Не забудьте указать `__declspec(dllexport)` для всех, и добавочно `extern "C"` для сишных функций. Реализуйте функции как угодно, чтобы компилятор скомпилировал это.

Если у вас декорированные C++-сигнатуры (они выглядят как-то так: `?test@@YGXXZ`) их можно превратить в правильные C++-декларации при помощи [утилиты `undname`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx):

```
...> undname ?test@@YGXXZ
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?test@@YGXXZ"
is :- "void __stdcall test(void)"
```

Если у вас есть header, идущий с библиотекой, то ничего угадывать (с риском ошибиться и получить креш) не надо, просто возьмите прототипы функций оттуда (только не забудьте поменять `__declspec(dllimport)` на `__declspec(dllexport)`).

Скомпилируйте полученный файл в .obj при помощи команды

```
cl /c /Ob0 dllname.cpp
```

Ключ `/c` нужен, чтобы компилятор произвёл .obj, а `/Ob0` — чтобы не занилайнил случайно какие-нибудь функции, которые ему покажутся ненужными (это может быть нужно в случае экспорта классов, и в любом случае не повредит).

Имея .obj, вы можете получить .lib и .def при помощи команды

```
lib /def: dllname.obj
```

Comment: Я еще думал дизассемблировать и пересобрать. Что вы думаете об этом?

Comment: @Cerbo: Ну, если дизассемблер настолько умный, что воссоздаст таблицу экспорта, то почему бы и нет?

Comment: Таблицу/заголовки вручную придется делать естественно. Мне кажется такой подход более кроссплатформенный? И вообще неплохо бы всю эту красоту утилитой оформить - было бы круто.

Comment: @Cerbo: Не, и не надейтесь. :( Потому что name mangling у каждого компилятора свой. Ну и утилиты для каждого компилятора свои. Мой ответ жёстко привязан к майкрософтовскому стеку.