# DEF файл для DLL, перегрузка функций

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, c++builder

В *dll* есть 2 функции:

```
func1(void)
func1(int)
```

как в *def-файле* задать имена для них?

```
EXPORTS
myfunc = func1
```

ведь конструкция выше не указывает для какой из них я даю имя и приводит к ошибке при компиляции:

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 неразрешенных внешних элементов,
```

или для *dll* нельзя перегружать функции?

Comment: наоборот: myfunc=func1

Comment: исправил, но проблему это не решает.

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453301/10105. Для C++-функций вы должны сдекорировать имя.

Comment: Но вообще-то, вы должны настроить среду, чтобы она сама создавала нужные файлы.

Comment: Мне это нужно для динамического подключения библиотеки, я уже различные варианты настройки перепробовал, без def - файла, названия функций указываемые для GetProcAddress неприемлемые,даже если использовать extern C.